# Save image from Camera using Opencv Example

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opencv, ios5

I have used [this code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_for_ios_book_samples/tree/master/Chapter15_DetectingFacialFeatures/Chapter15_DetectingFacialFeatures) from the [IOS examples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_for_ios_book_samples). And tried to save the images from camera. The issue is that the image is getting saved but with a blue tint as below.

[image]

The below is the code I used to save the image.

```
 - (void)processImagecv::Mat&image
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    UIImage * convertedImage = [ViewController imageWithCVMat:image];

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbumconvertedImage CGImage] orientationALAssetOrientation)[convertedImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error)
        {
            // TODO: error handling
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: success handling
            NSLog(@"Success";

        }
    }];

    TS(DetectAndAnimateFaces);
    faceAnimator->detectAndAnimateFaces(image);
    TE(DetectAndAnimateFaces);
}
```

Comment: The channels for image you've posted are reversed, ie instead of RGB order it has BGR, namely green red and blue channels are swapped.

Comment: @marol thanks for the reply. That fixed the issue. Please post it as an answer. It will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a given image order of channels is reversed, ie instead from opencv default representation BGR the image has the representation RGB, namely channel red and blue are swapped.